# fetch firstname using userID from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following mysql table:
Table Name:PaymentHitory

```
journeyID | passengerID  | driverID 
---------------------------  
1         |    1         |3  
2         |    2         |4
```

Table Name:UserInformation

```
userID | firstName
------------------
1      |    ABC         
2      |    XYZ        
3      |    PQR         
4      |    MSN
```

I want result like

```
 journeyID | passengerName  | driverName 
------------------------------------------  
    1      |    ABC         |PQR  
    2      |    XYZ         |MSN
```

Comment: driverName is not in all the two tables,then how will you retrieve that

Comment: Where is the `passengerName` and `driverName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple join on the tables:

```
select journeyID, pax.firstName as passengerName, dri.firstName as driverName 
    from PaymentHistory pay 
    join UserInformation pax on pay.passengerID = pax.userID 
    join UserInformation dri on pay.passengerID = dri.userID
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure !! You will get credit from question owner.